# Debian 8: can't get ClamAV to listen on TCP 3310

Tags: tcp, debian-jessie, clamav

I am trying to get Clamav-daemon running on a Debian 8 system so that it will listen on TCP port 3310. I have done the following:

```
aptitude install clamav-daemon
```

Then modified `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` so that it now has the following at the top:

```
# Added by me
TCPSocket 3310
TCPAddr localhost
# Already existed
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
FixStaleSocket true
LocalSocketGroup clamav
LocalSocketMode 666
```

Restarted the service using `service clamav-daemon restart`.

I am finding that `netstat -tap | grep clam` is not returning anything. Running `ps aux | grep clam` returns:

```
clamav   18559 11.4 10.3 649212 399604 ?       Ssl  14:38   0:15 /usr/sbin/clamd --foreground=true
```

There is an autogenerated file `/etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.socket.d/extend.conf` that contains:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
SocketUser=clamav
ListenStream=/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
SocketGroup=clamav
SocketMode=666
```

The only thing I can see in the logs is:

```
TCP: No tcp AF_INET/AF_INET6 SOCK_STREAM socket received from systemd
```

Does anyone know why I may be having trouble getting ClamAV to run on `TCP:3310`?

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the other suggestions above and couldn't get it to work.

However, running `dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon` and choosing TCP early on in the configuration options (rather than UNIX) and defaults for everything else worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

simply running

```
dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon
```

and choosing TCP socket and required port and interface ip (can be any) will get this working properly . You can accept defaults for all other values or specify them.

Answer (score 1):

I now have it working but it is no where near as nice to configure as it was on Debian 7.

I can only have either TCP or unixsocket (not sure why) but not both running. Hence I am using:

/etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.socket.d/extend.conf

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=
SocketUser=clamav
ListenStream=3310
```

/etc/clamav/clamd.conf only has:

```
TCPSocket 3310
```

and does not have the unix socket information in it. So this is REMOVED:

```
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
FixStaleSocket true
LocalSocketGroup clamav
LocalSocketMode 666
```

Then in order to get Exim4 to use it I have:

```
av_scanner = clamd:127.0.0.1:local
```

and I couldn't use `localhost` in there. It had to be `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

First purge everything clamav related:

```
apt-get purge clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam clamav-milter clamdscan clamassassin
```

Then re-install:

```
apt-get install clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon clamav-freshclam clamav-milter clamdscan clamassassin
```

Then in /etc/clamav/clamd.conf add

```
TCPSocket 3310
TCPAddr 127.0.0.1
```

-above- the existing LocalSocket entry. Else it set things up but times out during execution.
Then in /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.socket.d/extend.conf add

```
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:3310
```

at the bottom.
This will leave the Unix Socket operating as expected and create a listener on port 3310 using "init" as the conduit to the socket.
Then re-start the service:

```
service clamav-daemon restart
```

and check that init is listening on port 3310:

```
netstat -anp | grep 3310
```

Then test out ThunderBird's Add-Ons -> clamdrib -> Preferences -> Test

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough rep here to comment (as my solution is on a different distro), but on an install of ubuntu 16.04, this worked for me:

modifying clamav-daemon.socket directly:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
ListenStream=xx.xx.xx.xx:3310
SocketUser=clamav
SocketGroup=clamav
RemoveOnStop=True
```

Adding it to extend.conf did not work for me, but when i commented everything out of extend.conf and reloaded and restarted it listened on both.

Before this change i saw the same issue as  @Doahh

Answer (score 0):

After tested many times on Ubuntu 16.04, i got it working.

- Comment out all `ListenStream=` in `/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.socket`. If you don't comment out them, you will get error like `TCP: Received more than two file descriptors from systemd` and clamav cannot start.
- Add your own `ListenStream=` line(s) in `/etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.socket.d/extend.conf`. multiple `ListenStream=` (one socket, one network port) is supported like this:

`[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
ListenStream=xx.xx.xx.xx:3310
SocketUser=clamav
SocketGroup=clamav
RemoveOnStop=True`