# Clamav TCP 3310 setup Debian

Tags: debian-jessie, clamav, startup-scripts

I've run into this problem which is weird. I'm using Debian jessie I have setup clamav to listen also on port 3310 with the `TCPSocket 3310` option.

After saving the changes to the config file I restart the daemon with `service clamav-daemon restart` and check if its listening on port 3310 with `lsof -i tcp:3310` and it is not.

If I run the daemon manually with `clamd --config=/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` the everything works perfectly. I have tried to check if there is a `/etc/defaults/clam` script but there is none. Where can I set the preferences for the startup script to use the config file?

Comment: Try: http://serverfault.com/questions/798587/debian-8-cant-get-clamav-to-listen-on-tcp-3310

Comment: @Lenniey Did bump into that question but didn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway